# Inversion with the word 'whatsoever'

Tags: word-order, construction

Is it possible to make an inversion with the word 'whatsoever'?

For example, is this sentence correct?

> Whatsoever should you keep your mobile phone switched off during the performance.

Comment: Pro tip: If you're not certain how a word is sposta be used, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

*Whatsoever* doesn't make any sense in that sentence. I wonder what you intend it to mean.

You could say "Under no circumstances whatsoever should you leave your mobile phone switched on during the performance", where *whatsoever* adds emphasis to the negative statement.

Answer (score 1):

No, ***whatsoever*** is not used with inversion in this way. But even without inversion your sentence does not sound right. Note that:

> You use ***whatsoever*** after a noun group in order *to emphasize a **negative** statement*. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whatsoever))

> used after a negative phrase to add emphasis to the idea that is being expressed:
>
> - He has no respect for authority *whatsoever*. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whatsoever))

I think your sentence is better written simply, *whatsoever happens* or *in any circumstance whatsoever* are heavy, and *should* can be rude.

It should be enough to say

> Keep your mobile phone switched off during the performance, please.

Overemphasising such a notice might actually have the opposite effect to the one intended.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the conventional usage:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whatsoever)
> Whatsoever, adverb
> used after a negative phrase to add emphasis to the idea that is being expressed:
> *He has no respect for authority whatsoever.*
> *I can honestly say that I have no interest whatsoever in the royal family.*

The adverb may therefore be understood as:
*He has no respect {none, in any circumstances} for authority*
or
*I can honestly say that I have no interest {none, in any circumstances} in the royal family.*

Your example has no negative to intensify or emphasise, so it is not possible to use *whatsoever* in the conventional way.

However, it might be argued that a related sentence with inversion and embedded negative is valid:

*Whatsoever, you should not switch on your mobile phone during performance.*

to be understood as:

*{in any circumstance} you should not switch on your mobile phone during performance.*

However, this is not a common usage and cannot be recommended.